# Zombie.js testing framework, write to a file

Tags: node.js, javascript-framework, zombie.js

I have not found anything yet about being able to write to a file with Zombie.js.
I realize that js doesn't normally allow writing to files, but is it possible to combine Node.js with Zombie.js?

Does anyone know if it's at all possible to write to a file with the Zombie.js framework?

I'm really just attempting to dump the contents of an html page when the test fails, as I won't be around to see it fail.

Comment: Zombie.js runs on node.js, so: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.9/api/fs.html#fs.writeFile

Answer (score 0):

Since Zombie.js is built on Node.js, you can use the node fs module as @Jim Schubert suggested.

```
fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello Node', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('It\'s saved!');
});
```

[Manual](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.9/api/fs.html)